# .NET WebMethod FileUpload

Tags: .net, ajax, file-upload, webmethod

is possible to upload a file by using FileUpload Control and WebMethod?

I would like to avoid the UpdatePanel and ScriptManagers.

How can I do it? What kind of parameter the Web Method would be? Is there any example?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is not good enough: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

Answer (score 2):

I could not find solution you asked using `WebMethod` so I come up with alternative solution which is using `HTTPHandler` or better known as `ASPX` control/page.

To achieve what you wanted, I use **Valums File Upload**, there are many alternative out there but this is the one that I found very suitable for my case. You can find more information, documentation and download the javascript code here:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

The code also give example of how to handle the request in *server side* however, it doesn't include code example in *.net* so I found this project.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetHandlerAjaxUpload.aspx

Which use **Valums File Upload** and handle the file upload request using *.Net C#* on server side.

To summarize, here is how you use the **Valums File Upload** on **client side**:

1. Make sure reference the **CSS** and **Javascript** file downloaded from **Valum File Upload** website.
2. Use this code for creating *file upload control*

   ```
   <div id="divFileUpload">
       <noscript>
           <p>
               Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
       </noscript>
   </div>
   ```
3. Use this javascript code to setup the *file upload control*

   ```
   $(function () {
       var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
           element: document.getElementById('divFileUpload'),
           action: 'FileUpload.ashx',
           onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
               if (responseJSON.Success) {
                   alert("Success");
               }
           }
       });
   });
   ```

On the **server side**:

1. Create **ASHX** file to handle request from the client side.
2. Sample code

   ```
   public class FileUpload : IHttpHandler
   {
       public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
       {
           //Save the file here

           //Return Json value to client
           context.Response.Write("{ \"Success\": true }");
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Very important**, return JSON type to the client.

For more detail about how to handle the request from client side, please refer to the URL above.

All credits go to the **Andrew Valums** for the *Valums File Upload* and **Syed BASHAR** for the *.Net server code using Valums File Upload*.

Comment: May not be what he was looking for, but it was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: That may help I think. But still thats not passing to webmethod. I think using xhr I can convert a file into utf-8 and send to a webmethod. is it possible to do so?