# How can I upload a file using Ajax to asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

How can I asynchronously Upload file to asp.net Website (Webforms) without any post backs?

Comment: Can this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155069/net-webmethod-fileupload ?

Comment: check this out http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/ajax-asyncfileupload-control-example-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple to use [jQuery Forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form) for this purpose. We can use it in asp webforms like shown below.

HTML / ASPX Page

```
    <form id="myForm" action="fileupload.ashx" method="post"> 
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
        File: <input type="file" name="filetoupload" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
    </form>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
        // attach handler to form's submit event 
        $('#myForm').submit(function () {
            // submit the form 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit();
            // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Pure HTML used in this example. If aspx webforms then, there will be only one form tag in a page.

Add a WebHandler (.ashx extension) to Website.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    HttpPostedFile MyFile=context.Request.Files["filetoupload"];
    if (MyFile.ContentLength > 0 && MyFile != null)
    {
        MyFile.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath("Path/On/Server"));
    }
    context.Response.Write("Saved Successfully");
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```